# How to call S3 using aws cli commands in Lambda Function(Bash Script)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

Am using custom environment to run bash script in a lambda function. I have included a layer to support AWS CLI functions. But am not successful calling a s3 bucket. Here is the sample I tried inside hello.sh file. The line I have commented works providing function arn but the aws s3 list buckets did not work.

```
function handler () {
    EVENT_DATA=$1
    echo $EVENT_DATA
   #DATA=`/opt/awscli/aws lambda get-function --function-name testshellinlambda --query 'Configuration.FunctionArn' --output text`
    DATA =`/opt/awscli/aws aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[].Name'`
    RESPONSE="{\"statusCode\": 200, \"body\": \"$DATA\"}"
    echo $RESPONSE
}
```

Do any one has similar experience?Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: There's a space after your variable name in the `aws s3api` call, along with a `aws` option to the `aws` command.  Both will be fatal to a bash script.

Comment: Additionally, the RESPONSE variable won't be syntactically correct JSON, which will probably cause problems with whoever's consuming the response.

Comment: In the `RESPONSE` line, you cannot wrap the whole response in double-quotes (`"`) while also using that character _inside_ the quoted text. Use a single-quote (`'`) to wrap the content.